# Artillery - A lambda function has exited with with an error. Reason: artillery error

Tags: aws-lambda, performance-testing, load-testing, artillery

I am getting the following error when running a load test via artillery on aws lambda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsxPr.png)

The same file was working fine back in september 2023.

The yml file is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOTne.png)

The command run on nodejs console is as follows:

artillery run rediscache.yml --platform aws:lambda --platform-opt region=us-east-1

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to upgrade to version 2.0.1 or later (preferably latest, which is currently v2.0.7, as there are some Lambda issues that get solved between 2.0.1 and 2.0.7).

As explained [here](https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/issues/2543) this was due to a bug in dependency management that was solved in v2.0.1. No breaking changes of this kind will happen with versions after that.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. A silly question - how do you actually upgrade artillery.io to be run with the the version 2.0.1 or the latest version on AWS? I actually have limited access rights on AWS

Comment: i was able to resolve the issue by just updating to the latest artillery version on my machine:
npm install -g artillery@latest artillery-pro@latest

Comment: Yes, I meant only the Artillery version on your machine (or the machine that triggers the tests)! `npm install -g artillery@latest` is fine :)

Also, note that you don't need artillery-pro to run Lambda tests. And actually neither Fargate tests - that package is actually being deprecated.